# Session not established in iPhone browser, but working on other mobile devices

Tags: iphone, session, mobile, web

I'm creating a mobile website, which I have been testing it through symbian browsers(Nokia). Sessions established are all working fine in it, but when I did my test in an iPhone, despite being able to log in, my session variable seems to be empty. Is a different approach needed to for iPhone? Or am I doing something wrong?

FYI:

I'm using php sessions(session_start()).

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the iPhone is configured to accept cookies: Check the "Accept Cookies" setting under Safari in the Settings app.

Comment: if problem solved based on reply Caleb's reply , please choose it as an answer. :)